# What is the Super User community for?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have accounts on Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu and they cover almost all my queries. I just joined Super User, and I want to know which topics are supported and which types of questions are asked in this community.

Comment: This topic should ask in the community :)

Comment: `See [Tour], [Help], and [Meta]`: See [Tour], [Help], and [Meta].

Comment: See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Also, please try to at least take the [tour] every time you go to new site.

Answer (score 5):

Well amongst other things, we predate AU, and our scope was meant to compliment SO's programming centric viewpoint.

Clearly you're a programmer, who uses ubuntu. There's people with non programming questions to do with computers who may or may not use ubuntu. Or might be [ewoks](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). Many hardware questions are on topic here, and we have a *broader* tho overlapping scope with many of the newer sites, the young whippersnappers.

That said, our tour and help pages go into our scope in detail, and its all there.